# SYN_SENT issue from java program

Tags: java, database, multithreading, sockets

In my app, when my application server starts, i am creating 5 threads and each thread is a as400 server database connection. And each thread(java program) will make a as400 connection for every one minute.
But weekly, for few reasons, one of as400 database server goes down for 1-2 hours and java thread associated  hits this DB server for every one minute. At this point time my web App is stuck and I can't even access the URL.

**And from the linux console, when I did netstat -an, I had seen one server status is SYN_SENT which is down.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to adjust the various socket options.
Guide here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/socketOpt.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use some kind of [database] connection pool, rather than opening a new connection every minute.

Answer (score 0):

The server simply doesn't accept connections and the code connecting doesn't use any meaningful timeout, nor it's made to detect faulty servers. SYN_SENT means that the remote machine (AS/400) doesn't establish the connection. If possible try and remove that particular server from the list of the available ones.

If you open the connections directly (yourself): post your code. I will help you do it w/ a timeout and eventually loop among the available servers.

Comment: Thanks! it was implemented using a normal jdbc drivermanager connection.As you said, I may remove a server which is down from list of servers but the concept is I have to reconnect to this server when it is up! All the as400 servers will be down for 1-2 hours in a week but not at same time :( For this reason, I can't remove this server from the list of servers.

Comment: there are a few ways to discover if the server is up. 1st is ICMP ping (InetAdrress.isReachable()) and 2nd is normal TCP socket (open w/ a timeout). Use one thread on the background that test servers health and dynamically manages the list of the available server. I'm sorry for the late reply, didn't notice your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I'll implement this change!